# Bash script for deleting multiple users based upon date and UID

Tags: arrays, bash, split, cut

I am working on a bash script that deletes users based upon two things the date it was created and the user ID. If the date is before the date given in the terminal and the User ID is greater than 1000 the user should be deleted from the system. I have some code written out and it has given me alot of issues because the file that takes in the information with the username, date created, and ID needs to be split or "cut". Is there a better way to go about this then they way I did with breaking the pieces into an array?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo $0 "<date(year/month/day) filename>"
        exit 1
fi

dateForDeletion=$1
listOfUsers=$2

for i in `cat $listOfUsers` | while IFS='/t' read username date; do
        ${array[0]}="$username"
        ${array[1]}="$date"
        uid=`id -u ${array[0]}`
        if [$dateForDeletion < $date] && [uid > 1000] ; then
                `sudo userdel $username`
        fi
done
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read this [Bash PitFalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Answer (score 1):

You really should start smaller and build up, testing each statement individually before adding more. Here are some issues with your code:

1. You're using a strange amalgamation of a for and while loop.
2. `IFS="/t"` appears to try to set `IFS` to a tab. This should be `IFS=$'\t'`
3. `${array[0]}="$username"` is not a valid assignment. You should use `array[0]="$username"`, though I'm not sure why you're assigning it to an array in the first place.
4. `[$dateForDeletion < $date]` is not a valid condition/command. It should be `[[ $dateForDeletion < $date ]]` (assuming the dates are yyyy-mm-dd format or something that can be compared as strings).
5. `[uid > 1000]` is not a valid condition/command. It should be `[ "$uid" -gt 1000 ]`
6. `` `sudo userdel $username` `` should not have backticks around it.

Here's how your loop should look:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r username date
do
  uid=$(id -u "$username")
  if [[ $dateForDeletion < $date && $uid -gt 1000 ]]
  then
    sudo userdel "$username"
  fi
done < "$listOfUsers"
```